# Turning stdin input into an integer array Java

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read user input from a scanner into an integer array, I currently have this:

```
int [] arr1 = {Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine().split(" "))};
```

But i am given the error

```
String[] cannot be converted to String

Any help would be much appreciated :)
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` converts **single** strings to integers. But you attempt to use it on a `String[]` (result of `split`), so multiple strings. You have to execute the method individually on all elements of the `String[]` and then collect the `int`s back to an array.

Answer (score 1):

```java
sc.nextLine().split(" ") //This returns String[]
int a = Integer.parseInt("") //Integer.parseInt requires one String param.
```

Try below code:

```java
String input = sc.nextLine();
String[] inputs = input.split(" ");

List<Integer> ints = Arrays.stream(inputs).
map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Check the document:
API: [Integer.parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))
[String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))